# What did Philip José Farmer base "The Nine" on?

Tags: history-of, inspiration, philip-jose-farmer

Philip José Farmer wrote [several books](http://www.goodreads.com/series/107336-secrets-of-the-nine) (at least two) that featured a nefarious group called *The Nine*. Those books were *A Feast Unknown* and *Lord of the trees/the Mad Goblin*(a two in one novel). These books paid homage to Tarzan and Doc Savage. I don't recall such a group of evil doers in either of the original series.

The heroes of these homages are based on Tarzan and Doc Savage. What was the Nine based on?

EDIT- I was able to track down what I hoped would be the answer, [The Empire of the Nine](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/074740366X) , but it turns out to be an omnibus of the two novels I referenced in the question.

Comment: some readers like to see these books as part of a larger picture: http://www.pjfarmer.com/woldnewton/Pulp3.htm

Answer (score 2):

Farmer may have adapted at least part of "The Nine" from Chinese myths about immortality.  The immortal member of "The Nine" is XauXaz, which could be a reference to [Xu Fu](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xu_Fu), a court sorcerer in the Zhou Dynasty circa 255 BC who made two extensive voyages in search of elixirs granting immortality.  This is pure speculation on my part, but the preoccupation of "The Nine" with such elixirs seems fitting with this.

Apart from the this, it appears that "The Nine" are an original creation of Farmer.

Comment: It's a pity PJF didn't expand upon them. They were quite intriguing.